# How to upgrade a chaincode after modification?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to hyperledger and is going through the example [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/education/tree/master/LFS171x/fabric-material/tuna-app) . I am tried to play around the chaincode but is now stuck at the part where I am suppose to upgrade the chaincode

I have tried to execute the peer chaincode upgrade within the docker peer node:

```
peer chaincode upgrade -n tuna-app -p github.com/tuna-app
```

but end up with the error

```
 Error getting (testchainid) orderer endpoint: Error endorsing GetConfigBlock: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = chaincode error (status: 500, message: "GetConfigBlock" request failed authorization check for channel [testchainid]: [Failed to get policy manager for channel [testchainid]])
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify the channel name for which you'd like to upgrade the chaincode, also need to specify args and new version. Moreover you have to specify the ordering service endpoints so peer cli will be able to submit the upgrade transaction:

```
peer chaincode upgrade -n tuna-app -v 2.0 \
               -c '{"Args":[""]}' \
               -p github.com/tuna-app -C mychannel \
               -o orderer:7051
```

You can find more [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/commands/peerchaincode.html#peer-chaincode-upgrade).

Comment: I think this answer is deprecated. At least, the link is dead.

Comment: The port for orderer is usually 7050, and 7051 is usually allocated for peers. So someone new to hyperledger fabric might get confused there.

Comment: I have updated the dead link with actual upgrade command described in hyperledger doc

Answer (score 1):

Here you have some basic script in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

PRV_VERSION='v2';
VERSION='v3';

CONTAINER_IDS=$(docker ps -a | grep "mycc-$PRV_VERSION" | awk '{print $1}')
docker rm -f $CONTAINER_IDS

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/peer/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com \
    peer chaincode install \
    -n mycc \
    -v $VERSION \
    -p /etc/hyperledger/chaincode \
    -l node;

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/peer/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer1.org1.example.com \
    peer chaincode install \
    -n mycc \
    -v $VERSION \
    -p /etc/hyperledger/chaincode \
    -l node;

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/peer/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp" peer0.org2.example.com \
    peer chaincode install \
    -n mycc \
    -v $VERSION \
    -p /etc/hyperledger/chaincode \
    -l node;

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/peer/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp" peer1.org2.example.com \
    peer chaincode install \
    -n mycc \
    -v $VERSION \
    -p /etc/hyperledger/chaincode \
    -l node;

sleep 10;
ORDERER_CA=/etc/hyperledger/organizations/users/Admin@example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
docker exec  -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" \
             -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/peer/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" \
             peer0.org1.example.com \
    peer chaincode upgrade \
    -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA \
    -C mychannel \
    -n mycc \
    -v $VERSION \
    -c '{"Args":[""]}' \
    -p /etc/hyperledger/chaincode

ORDERER_CA=/etc/hyperledger/organizations/users/Admin@example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
docker exec  -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP" \
             -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/peer/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp" \
             peer0.org2.example.com \
    peer chaincode upgrade \
    -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA \
    -C mychannel \
    -n mycc \
    -v $VERSION \
    -c '{"Args":[""]}' \
    -p /etc/hyperledger/chaincode
```

You need of course share some certs to your peer0.org1 and of course the chaincode itself (in js or go), here you have some docker-compose.yml part:

```
peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:   base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    volumes:
        - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer
        - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/peer/users
        - ./channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/organizations/users
        - ./src/github.com/example_cc/node:/etc/hyperledger/chaincode
```

Then you can check the logs by:

```
docker logs dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-v3 -f
```

I need to say, that upgrading chaincode in development take the same amount of time as just recreate whole blockchain (without pulling new images - this should be removed from ./runApp.sh script).

Comment: I think this is not an update script. It just destroys every thing and restarts everything. The good script should include the cmd "peer upgrade ..."