# Error - chaincode exists

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm getting this error when trying to start running my chaincode:

Command: `composer network start -c adminCardLessor -n block-aviation-network -V 0.0.1 -A admin -C ./credentials/lessor/admin-pub.pem -f delete_me.card`

> Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
>   Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: chaincode exists block-aviation-network)

I successfully installed my chaincode on each of my peers but can seem to start it due to the above error...

Does anyone have any experience with this error or how to resolve it?

Comment: That error suggests that the network with that exact name and version is already started - check if you have docker containers running for that version with `docker ps`

Comment: I'm not using docker unfortunately - I'm using the starter plan as a test enviroment, using the starter kit to deploy it. It says the chaincode is installed on the peers, but it says its `Not Running`. I just dont know how to get it running on other peers rather than the one that was used to set up the network (org1).

Comment: I encountered the same error even when incrementing the chaincode version.

Answer (score 2):

Because the chaincode already exists on the network, you can only upgrade it, because I am assuming the network is not starting because you made some changes. Look toward questions such as [How to upgrade a chaincode after modification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47330576/how-to-upgrade-a-chaincode-after-modification) and then try starting the network. This should solve your problem.

Comment: I updated the code to a new version using a command as shown for each org: `composer network upgrade -c  admin@blockchain-network -n block-aviation-network -V 0.0.2`. Changing the card and credentials for each org.  This only started running the chaincode in the first organisation however and when I try to do a `composer network start` on the other channels I get the error `chaincode exists block-aviation-network`. Should `composer network upgrade` start runinng the chaincode aswell?

Comment: @SimonMullaney In a similar situation, any luck with this one?

Comment: @MrudavShukla My problem was that I had already started running my chaincode. Then I was adding more peers to my network and trying to start the chaincode again. I was experiencing this problem then because chaincode had already been deployed. My way around this was to deploy all nodes at once and start them all at the same time. Other ways that might work would be to stop the peers & start them or upgrade all peers to a new chaincode version & start them thereafter.

Comment: @SimonMullaney Yes once the update is successful. Just start the composer-rest-server and use the new updated contract.